# Does reputation decrease if rewarding a bounty to own question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I know I do not have enough reputation to reward bounties to questions, but I have a question about bounties.

If you reward a bounty to your own question, does Stack Overflow subtract the full bounty amount you rewarded to your question? Or does it subtract a few reputation as a 'fee'? Or does your reputation stay the same?

Comment: You can't reward your own answer. Once you set a bounty, that rep is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're a little confused about how bounties work.

- You don't award a bounty to a question, you *offer* a bounty on a question. The reward goes to an *answer*, if any good ones are posted.
- As mentioned in the comments, you can't award a bounty to yourself. You can place a bounty on your own question, but it can only be awarded to somebody else's answer. One way or another, once you've placed the bounty, all of the points are gone from your account forever.

You can read more about how bounties work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).